# Hystrix with Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, hystrix

I am trying to see the feasibility of using Spring Integration in my new project. It is a microservices based project with a central component where I want to put in place Spring integration component which essentially act as a orchestration component which will orchestrate the calls to all the external microservices.
The current issue is I am trying but I am not yet able to get spring cloud  hystrix circuit breaker work with Spring integration. I tried java dsl as well, but for the moment I am clueless. I really want to use hystrix for the circuit breaker so that I can use the hystrix dashboard with the project as well.
Any help or a small example would really help

Comment: What's the problem? What's the stacktrace?

Comment: Any samples from you side, please, to figure out where you are?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the story is about Circuit Breaker, you should consider to implement `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice` for that  Hystrix command. [Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) on the matter.

You can borrow some ideas how to do that from the existing `RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice`. The [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more) on the matter.

I think the feature with `fallbackMethod` could be possible as a combination of the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with its `failureChannel` and `trapException` to `true` and `RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice` as the next in a chain. That way you all the exceptions downstream will be caught by the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and send to the channel which we may treat as a `fallbackMethod` in Hystrix terms.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that out. Although I am not sure I really understood how to implement the fallback method. Could you please explain it a bit more and also is there a way to implement the cached functioanlity as well?

Comment: About Cache: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2105. There is no `method` notation in the Spring Integration, but there is `MessageChannel`. So, in terms of Spring Integration that should be `fallbackChannel`. But since `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` provides already `failureChannel`, there is just enough to add this advice into the chain before `RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice`. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it. But if I am not wrong, this is the spring integration way. I deally I would like to implement hystrix with spring integration in the project. Primary reason is I would like to use hystrix dashboard maybe with turbine for monitoring the application. Is there a clean way I can acheive that?

Comment: As I said , you need to take a look the way to implement `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice` go historic command. There is no other way to hook Spring Integration endpoint. You can, of course, consider to mark service method with `@HystrixCommand`, like we do with `@Transactional` , together with `@ServiceActivator`

Answer (score 0):

Following the thread answered by Artem Bilan, using an advice chain with ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice and RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice, and configuring a fallbackChannel, this receives an message without a replyChannel needed to fallback a predefined message to the user. How to setup the fallbackChannel appropiately.