# Spring-Integration http:outbound-gateway with Hystrix

Tags: spring-integration, hystrix, spring-integration-http

Is there a way I can wrap a http:outbound gateway REST API call with Hystrix Command. I saw some reference to using a custom request handler advice, not sure how I would go about doing it.

Comment: Please, explain why do you need Hystrix there and why do you think that there is something like `fallback method` somewhere around that http:Outbound, so you can apply Hystrix?

Answer (score 0):

See here: [Wrap spring integration outbound gateway calls with hystrix command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786571/wrap-spring-integration-outbound-gateway-calls-with-hystrix-command). I can't close your question as `duplicate` because nobody voted for my answer. But still: the same solution must be applied for your use-case:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "serviceChannel")
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "serviceFallback")
public String myService(String payload) {
    // Some external service call
}

public String serviceFallback(String payload) {
    // some fallback logic
}
```

See also sample in my sendbox: https://github.com/artembilan/sendbox/tree/master/spring-integration-with-hystrix